# Can I restrict nose coverage output to directory (rather than package)?

Tags: python, code-coverage, nose, nosetests

My SUT looks like:

```
foo.py
bar.py
tests/__init__.py [empty]
tests/foo_tests.py
tests/bar_tests.py
tests/integration/__init__.py [empty]
tests/integration/foo_tests.py
tests/integration/bar_tests.py
```

When I run `nosetests --with-coverage`, I get details for all sorts of
modules that I'd rather ignore.  But I can't use the
`--cover-package=PACKAGE` option because `foo.py` & `bar.py` are not in a
package.  (See the thread after
http://lists.idyll.org/pipermail/testing-in-python/2008-November/001091.html
for my reasons for not putting them in a package.)

Can I restrict coverage output to just foo.py & bar.py?

**Update** - Assuming that there isn't a better answer than [Nadia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/97828/nadia)'s below, I've asked a follow up question: ["How do I write some (bash) shell script to convert all matching filenames in directory to command-line options?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855265/how-do-i-write-some-bash-shell-script-to-convert-all-matching-filenames-in-dire)

Comment: With the latest versions of nose and coverage, the code in the test files is ignored under nose, so you shouldn't need to specify the package at all.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
--cover-package=foo --cover-package=bar
```

I had a quick look at nose source code to confirm: [This is the line](https://github.com/nose-devs/nose/blob/master/nose/plugins/cover.py)

```
    if options.cover_packages:
        for pkgs in [tolist(x) for x in options.cover_packages]:
```

Comment: I'm impressed that you looked at the source.  (I should have thought of that.)

But it shows I need to use "--cover-package=foo --cover-package=bar".  If you modify your answer I'll accept it (and vote it up).

Comment: Thanks for the note. I fixed the answer. I've never used nose before. But I thought I'd give the question a try since no one else answered.

Comment: Thanks Nadia.  You still need to remove the ".py" extensions,  since the arguments are the package names, not the file names.

Comment: Opps, sorry about the mistakes. Fixed :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is just wrong. That line you found doesn't prove anything, it just shows that the flag is converted and passed to the coverage tool as the "source=" keyword argument.The coverage tool takes paths as shown here:
https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/v4.5.x/source.html

Answer (score 15):

You can use:

```
--cover-package=.
```

or even set environment variable

```
NOSE_COVER_PACKAGE=.
```

Tested with nose 1.1.2

Comment: How can one achieve the same thing with options in setup.cfg?

Comment: I get coverage reported from site-packages using this :/

Comment: Do you use virualenv? I get also this, in virtualenv

Comment: Any idea how to handle in a virtualenv?

Answer (score 4):

I have a lot of top-level Python files/packages and find it annoying to list them all manually using --cover-package, so I made two aliases for myself. Alias `nosetests_cover` will run coverage with all your top-level Python files/packages listed in --cover-package. Alias `nosetests_cover_sort` will do the same and additionally sort your results by coverage percentage.

```
nosetests_cover_cmd="nosetests --with-coverage --cover-erase --cover-inclusive --cover-package=\$( ls | sed -r 's/[.]py$//' | fgrep -v '.' | paste -s -d ',' )"
alias nosetests_cover=$nosetests_cover_cmd
alias nosetests_cover_sort="$nosetests_cover_cmd 2>&1 | fgrep '%' | sort -nr -k 4"
```

Notes:

- This is from my .bashrc file. Modify appropriately if you don't use bash.
- These must be run from your top-level directory. Otherwise, the package names will be incorrect and coverage will silently fail to process them (i.e. instead of telling you your --cover-package is incorrect, it will act like you didn't supply the option at all).
- I'm currently using Python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 13.10, with nose version 1.3.0 and coverage version 3.7.1. This is the only setup in which I've tested these commands.
- In your usage, remove --cover-erase and --cover-inclusive if they don't match your needs.
- If you want to sort in normal order instead of reverse order, replace `-nr` with `-n` in the sort command.
- These commands assume that all of your top-level Python files/packages are named without a dot (other than the dot in ".py"). If this is not true for you, read Details section below to understand the command parts, then modify the commands as appropriate.

Details:

I don't claim that these are the most efficient commands to achieve the results I want. They're just the commands I happened to come up with.  =P

The main thing to explain would be the argument to --cover-package. It builds the comma-separated list of top-level Python file/package names (with ".py" stripped from file names) as follows:

- `\$` -- Escapes the `$` character in a double-quoted string.
- `$( )` -- Inserts the result of the command contained within.
- `ls` -- Lists all names in current directory (must be top-level Python directory).
- `| sed -r 's/[.]py$//'` -- In the list, replaces "foo_bar.py" with "foo_bar".
- `| fgrep -v '.'` -- In the list, removes all names without a dot (e.g. removes foo_bar.pyc and notes.txt).
- `| paste -s -d ','` -- Changes the list from newline-separated to comma-separated.

I should also explain the sorting.

- `2>&1` -- Joins stderr and stdout.
- `| fgrep '%'` -- Removes all output lines without a `%` character.
- `| sort -nr -k 4` -- Sorts the remaining lines in reverse numerical order by the 4th column (which is the column for coverage percentage). If you want normal order instead of reverse order, replace `-nr` with `-n`.

Hope this helps someone!  =)

Answer (score 3):

If you use [coverage:py 3.0](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/200904/coverage_v30_beta_2.html), then code in the Python directory is ignored by default, including the standard library and all installed packages.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this:

```
nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=foo,bar tests/*
```

I prefer this solution to the others suggested; it's simple yet you are explicit about which packages you wish to have coverage for. Nadia's answer involves a lot more redundant typing, Stuart's answer uses sed and still creates a package by invoking `touch __init__.py`, and
`--cover-package=.` doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone trying to do this with setup.cfg, the following works. I had some trouble figuring out how to specify multiple packages.

```
[nosetests]
with-coverage=1
cover-html=1
cover-package=module1,module2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
touch __init__.py; nosetests --with-coverage --cover-package=`pwd | sed 's@.*/@@g'`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can improve the accepted answer like so `--cover-package=foo,bar`